# How to disable Developer options in samsung galaxy s4?

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I have enabled the developer options on my samsung galaxy S4. Now I am unable to disable it, by clearing the data in settings in the application manager.

In application manager, under settings, the `CLEAR DATA` option is disabled, and I'm unable to clear the data.

How can I disable developer mode?

Comment: I don't have an S4, but in my "Settings->Developer Options" menu there is a toggle switch at the top of the screen to turn it off. It doesn't remove it from the Settings menu, but it turns them all off.

Comment: Android related? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33496/where-are-the-developer-options-in-android-4-2/33497#33497

Comment: Belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, since the question concerns a **developer setting**, and not some other random Android detail it is fine here.

Comment: Don't have a galaxy S4, but comparing on a recent nexus, perhaps you tried this for SettingsStorage (where it is greyed out) and not for Settings?  Of course it may well just be a minor vendor bug.

Answer (score 1):

- go to your apps (menu -settings - apps, or menu - manage apps)
- Under "All," scroll down until you find "Settings"
- Tap on settings and then clear data/cache
- This will NOT reset any settings, it will simply remove Developer options from the Settings menu

For your reference I found this on Google, it was the second search item.

Comment: The OP specifically says that the "Clear Data" option is disabled.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Apologies.